# Groups and sub-groups display broken after upgrade to 4.7.10

Tags: groups, 4.7.10, display

Hi After upgrading civicrm to v4.7.10 from 4.7.8, it looks like the display of groups and sub-groups has changed and is not partially broken.

The first group and has sub-groups is displayed showing that there are sub-groups. The second group that has sub-groups and sub-sub-groups shows as a regular group but not that it has sub-groups.

This prevents from accessing the sub-sub-groups. They can only be in searching for them in the Find so it appears to be a display issue only.

Comment: Is the issue only on the Manage Groups screen or is it when you try to add a contact to a sub-sub-group as well?

Comment: To answer your question, it is only on the Manage Groups page. When add a group and click on Add parent, you can see all the groups displayed in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to [CRM-19096](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19096) and/or [CRM-19219](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19219), and possibly [CRM-19272](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19272).

The first two are fixed with CiviCRM 4.7.11, which is officially released on September 7th, 2016.  The third one [has a fix available](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8942/files) but hasn't been scheduled into a release.

If you can't wait, and you know how to patch your CiviCRM, you can get the fixes from Github; if you don't know how, wait for CiviCRM 4.7.11, it's only a week away!

Comment: Thanks Jon for the feedback. I think we can wait a week as it is not critical. The way around it is to do a search of all groups and you can see all the groups this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, we downloaded version 4.7.11 (security upgrade). We tested it and the group and sub-group display error from 4.7.10 is now solved.

Thanks.